# ElasticSearch: Prevent (temporary) creation of replica

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

In a ElasticSearch server  (8.x) with phases of huge bulk inserts: Is it possible to pause the creation of replica while having the high insert/update phase so the entire cluster can focus on digesting the additional data as fast as possible? Yes I'm aware that in cases of a node fail there is high chance of data loss.
Or is there another way to get new data fast into the cluster without adding additional primary shards?

tried to set replica to zero - but this leads to high load while recreating all the replica after the insert phase is done.

Comment: Indeed setting replicas to 0 is a good way to speed up the bulk indexing, but suffers from the drawback of having to recreate them after indexing is over. As a quick test you should try to set `refresh_interval` to -1 in your index settings to [pause index refreshes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html#_unset_or_increase_the_refresh_interval) while you bulk insert and see how that helps.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.